# MVC 4 and autofac: DependencyResolutionException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I'm using the following code for registering all of my controllers:

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
  builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly)
           .OnActivated(a => a.Context.InjectUnsetProperties(a.Instance))
           .OnActivating(InjectInvoker);
}
private static void InjectInvoker(IActivatingEventArgs<object> obj)
{
    var invoker = obj.Context.ResolveOptional<IActionInvoker>();
    if (invoker != null)
    {
        ((Controller)obj.Instance).ActionInvoker = invoker;
    }
}
```

but now I have a controller that takes 2 interfaces of the same kind:

```
        builder.Register(c => new RestClient(Url1))
            .Named<IRestClient>("Url1")
           .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.Register(c => new RestClient(Url2))
            .Named<IRestClient>("Url2")
           .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    public HomeController(IRestClient r1, IRestClient r2)
```

I get the following error:
None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Site.Controllers.HomeController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'RestSharp.IRestClient r1' of constructor 'Void .ctor(RestSharp.IRestClient, RestSharp.IRestClient)'.
Which I did expect, so then
I've tried adding the following code:

```
        builder.Register(
            c =>
            new HomeController(
                               c.ResolveNamed<IRestClient>("Url1"),
                               c.ResolveNamed<IRestClient>("Url2")))
                             .As<IController>()
                             .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

which then I got the same error again.

so what is the correct way to register a controller in the kind of situation?
thanks.

Comment: Two things your custom controller registration should go **after** the `RegisterControllers` call and try it without the `.As<IController>()` part

Comment: Where do Url1 and Url2 come from, are these variables?

Comment: the code is an example...the variables are set from the config file, so it would be Properties.Settings.Default.Url1

Comment: nemesv:  yes that worked:)  you should post that as an answer.  also any insight on why that works would be appreciated.

Comment: @user261490 I've added it as an answer with some additional explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your controller **without the** `.As<IController>()` (or you need to use `.AsSelf()` but this is default setting).

You need to this because the framework will try to resolve your Controller with using the concrete type `HomeController` and not the `IController` interface (so the `RegisterControllers` method register all the controller with `.AsSelf()` internally).

So the following registration should work

```
builder.Register(
    c =>
        new HomeController(
            c.ResolveNamed<IRestClient>("Url1"),
            c.ResolveNamed<IRestClient>("Url2")))
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Note: you should have this call **after** the `RegisterControllers` call.